# capture bluetooth remote shutter event

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am wondering how/if I can capture in android an event triggered by a bluetooth remote shutter event.
For example one like this:
http://www.avancaproducts.com/en/shop/other/bluetooth-camera-shutter-remote/

I don't want to make a picture, but instead I want to send an Email or SMS when the remote control is pressed.

I would appreciate some tips or examples.

Comment: I have a similar issue, did you find a solution to your problem in the meantime?