# Using BLE shutter remote to control React Native app

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, hid

Is it possible to detect when a button has been pressed on a BLE HID device using [`react-native-ble-plx`](https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx)?

I want to use [these BLE remotes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MR1PHPZ) to have a cheap and robust way of controlling a React Native app with external devices (avoiding making a new project using ESP32 or it's variants would be preferred). When connected through the Android OS it works as simple volume up and volume down buttons - which triggers camera shutter, as intended. However, when connected to a BLE app (tested with [LightBlue](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.punchthrough.lightblueexplorer&hl=en&gl=US) and with a React native app) that functionality is gone.

I have a few of these remotes and need to detect when a button was pressed and which remote was pressed on. Because they are BLE and not Bluetooth classic more than one can be connected at the same time.

Detection of volume up and volume down actions works by using [`react-native-keyevent`](https://github.com/kevinejohn/react-native-keyevent) but only when the remotes are connected to the OS and there is no way to get which remote triggered the action.

By using this piece of code to try to monitor all characteristics only errors are returned:

```
await bleManager.connect(discoveredDevice);
let discoveredServices = (await (await discoveredDevice.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics()).services());
for (let iService = 0; iService < discoveredServices.length; iService++) {
    let characteristics = await discoveredServices[iService].characteristics();
    for (let iCharacteristic = 0; iCharacteristic < characteristics.length; iCharacteristic++) {
        characteristics[iCharacteristic].monitor((error: BleError | null, characteristic: Characteristic | null): void => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error.message);
                return;                        
            } else {
                console.log(characteristic?.value);                        
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The following error occurs for all `monitor()` calls - with different UUIDs:

```
ERROR  Characteristic 0000ae42-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb notify change failed for device ? and service 0000ae40-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

A screenshot containing the services and characteristics of the device captured within LightBlue can be found [here](https://ibb.co/jWD0Bm6)

This question might be duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44248326/capture-bluetooth-remote-shutter-event)

Comment: Are you sure the remotes are using Bluetooth Low Energy and not Bluetooth Classic? Could you add a screenshot from LightBlue to your question? I would be interested in the services and characteristics the device offers

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan I've added a screenshot at the end of the post

Comment: Android blocks the use of HID Bluetooth service. So no you can't do this.

Comment: hi @Emil where can i find more info about Android blocking HID Bluetooth services? that means that a HID device will never fire the notification on monitorCharacteristicForService ?

Comment: Not sure if it's documented anywhere but you can always look in the source code for AOSP.

Comment: hi @Emil thanks for your answer. So you saw that Android blocks the use of HID Bluetooth service on the source code?